# How to pass and display Calculation result on a New view/component in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-template

I created a simple calculator app. I have two component: Calculator and Result and use Angular router between them. Now I want to do this : When I perform a calculation in Calculation component, the result will be passed and displayed in another Result component. Can you show me some ways for this ?
[image]

[image]

calculator.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  public number1: number;
  public number2: number;
  public result: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  sum() {
    this.result = this.number1 + this.number2;
  }

  diff() {
    this.result = this.number1 - this.number2;
  }

  mult() {
    this.result = this.number1 * this.number2;
  }

  divi() {
    this.result = this.number1 / this.number2;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

calculator.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">CALCULATOR</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group value">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Value 1:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10 input-1">
                        <input [(ngModel)]='number1' class="form-control inp" type="number" name="num1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Value 2:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10 input-2">
                        <input [(ngModel)]='number2' class="form-control inp" type="number" name="num2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <br>
                <button class="butt" (click)='sum()'> + </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="butt" (click)='diff()'> - </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="butt" (click)='mult()'> x </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="butt" (click)='divi()'> / </button>
                <br><br><br>
            </div>
            {{result}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CalculatorComponent } from './calculator/calculator.component';
import { ResultComponent } from './result/result.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'calculator', component: CalculatorComponent },
{ path: 'result', component: ResultComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
    { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Angular Router</h1>
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/calculator" routerLinkActive="active">Calculator</a><br>
    <a routerLink="/result" routerLinkActive="active">Result</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: cant you use share service for this?

Comment: @Plochie yes, here my ```data.service.ts```.I haven't got any action on it.

Comment: I have added ways to transfer data via state and service. check the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this,

1. The simplest way can be to use state while navigating to `result` route from `calculator` route.

```js
this.router.navigate(['result'], { state: { result } });
```

This will put your result in `window.history.state` object, which then you can access from `result` component.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.resultValue = window.history.state.result;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jp6xa4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresult%2Fresult.component.ts)

2. You can also store the result in shared service and then access that variable from `result` component. Inject the service wherever required and store the retrieve data from it.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedServiceService {
  storeValue: number = 0;
  constructor() { }
}
```